# Searching for a manhwa/novel where the heroine is reincarnated as villain and forced to marry second male lead

Tags: story-identification, manga

The female main character is reincarnated into a Villain family where family members torture her secretly and make her act as a Villainess. They force her to marry the second male lead.

First male lead is his brother and heroine is white lotus. Both brothers at first love the heroine. Heroine tries to keep both brothers close but shows preference to the first male lead.

In many instances they twist her words to make the family mad at her. Like praising the heroine's white dress or not buying any jewelry is twisted and made to look like she is picky and sarcastic. There is an instance where she tried to help the household by applying modern day accounting techniques but is trapped by white lotus heroine.

In some spoilers I saw that once second male lead and the main character shift to the land allocated to them the second male leads' parents and become miserable  because the heroine, even though married to first male lead, starts to show her true colors.

Even their loyal accountant shifts to their territory later.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to have any science fiction or fantasy elements that would make it on-topic.

Comment: What does "Mc" mean? Is it a name?

Comment: @AndresF. - MC is **M**ain **C**haracter. ML is **M**ale **L**ead

Comment: @DavidW - The main character was reincarnated into a family. That seems fairly on-topic for us

Comment: @RoseAlice - This question is somewhat confusing. Can you confirm who said what to who?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/96179105-akuyaku-reijou-no-naka-no-hito? Lots of potential matches here; https://www.reddit.com/r/OtomeIsekai/comments/vw28c9/manga_with_white_lotus_ogfl/

Comment: @Valorum At this point every single manga seems to either be (a) reincarnation or (b) isekai; it's like it's table stakes.  Even if not a single other thing in the manga is fantastic or science fictional; at this point I'm starting to consider _just_ isekai or _just_ reincarnation not evidence of being on-topic.  (Evidently.)  At least not unless it is actually important to the plot.

Comment: @DavidW - And while that's not untrue, it would appear that being reincarnated into this family is a key plot point.

Comment: @Valorum I'm probably overthinking this, but ISTM that reincarnation and isekai are both lazy plot devices to give the protagonist outsider/observer status in their own life.  20 years ago it would have been easy amnesia or a wizard did it.  _Serial_ reincarnation, on the other hand, is plot-relevant.

Comment: @DavidW - Either way, it's definitely on-topic for us and this question should remain open until it's shown to be off-topic in some other way.

Comment: @Valorum is that a manga thing? I've only ever seen it used here by manga fans. Also inconsistently, they will spell out "male lead" but write "Mc"... Reeks of laziness to me.

Comment: @AndresF. - It's very much a manga and manhwa thing.

Comment: Sounds like "Survive as the Hero’s Wife".